# Invalid Byte Sequence in Docker postgres image

Tags: postgresql, docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to do the following on a [Docker postgres image](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/):

```
FROM docker.io/postgres

# Move script to the auto-startup folder of this Docker image
RUN mv some_script.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/some-script.sql

# Set the DB variables
ENV ENCODING UTF8
ENV POSTGRES_DB some_db
ENV POSTGRES_USER some_user
ENV POSTGRES_PASSWORD some_password
```

It is creating the first part of the 'some-script.sql' file, until it finds the following line:

```
INSERT INTO languages (language, two_character_code, english_name, native_name) VALUES ('es-es', 'es', 'Spanish', 'Español');
```

I suppose this goes wrong at the `Español` word, since it has an special character. However, it is strange that I can smoothly run this exact file in the same Docker environment using pgAdmin on Windows:

> Query returned successfully with no result in 296 msec.

(where the tables were created successfully)

What do I have to change to make it work via the Dockerfile?

Comment: This happens because the CLIENT_ENCODING of the database connection on which the script is executed doesn't match the actual encoding of the data send to the server. If the script is stored in utf8 encoding it should help to put `SET CLIENT_ENCODING TO 'utf8';` at the start of the script.

Comment: @Eelke, Thanks! You were right about the client encoding. I noticed the file encoding wasn't utf-8 but ansi, so changing the client encoding to 'WIN1252' worked (using [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1566418/5488275)).